# How to remove L-channel from Lab Image

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, opencv

I need to get a Lab image, but without the l-channel. Either by removing the l-channel or by splitting all three channels up and merging the a- and b-channel back together.

My code so far (not even anywhere next to solving this):

```
lab_image = cv2.cvtColor(numpy.array(color_images_array)[i], cv2.COLOR_RGB2LAB)

_, a, b = cv2.split(lab_image)
```

This code only splits the channels up, but doesn't merge the a- and b-channel...

Comment: Why bother deleting it - you could just ignore it and access the `a` and `b` channels in your subsequent processing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cv2.split` separates the channels from the image. You have to call `cv2.merge` function to merge them.

```
merged = cv2.merge((a,b))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `cv2.merge()`. The right syntax is:

```
merged = cv2.merge( (channel_1,channel_2,...) )
```

In your case:

```
merged = cv2.merge((a,b))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use Numpy's `delete()` function to delete the first channel (index=0) in the 3rd axis (axis=2) - whereby first axis corresponds to columns, second axis corresponds to rows and third axis corresponds to channels:

```
# Delete "L" channel from Lab image
ab = np.delete(lab_image, 0, 2)
```